# Mode using DescTools in R

Tags: r, desctools

I am using R and I've learned to calculate the Mode using CodeAcademy's curriculum. Basically CodeAcademy recommended using DescTools (which is an R Package that I've installed on my computer). The Mode should return the most commonly occurring value in a numerical vector. However, when I run this simple block of code my console in R isn't returning anything. It's just reprinting the line of code I've executed.

Is something wrong with my IDE or have I made a mistake in writing this block of code? I've read so many threads and used the ?Mode help function, but it seems that I've written the code properly from what I can tell. I'm just not getting any result to show up in my console when executing the code.

```
install.packages("DescTools")
require(DescTools)
?Mode
my_data <- c(15,8,9,15,12,13,2,15,13,8,13,6,7)
Mode2 <- Mode(my_data)
print(Mode2)
Mode2
view(Mode2)
```

As you can see in the code block above, I tried to use print() to view the data, I tried to just type Mode2 to render it to the workbook, and I tried using view(), but none of these lines result in any output in my console.

Comment: What do you get as output?

Comment: Well that is part of what is strange. No output. The console just re-prints that executed line of code in blue. Doesn't return a value at all, as if it's not calculating anything? No error, no output.

Comment: Do you get any error like this `DescTools::Mode(my_data)
Error in fastModeX(x, narm = FALSE) : 
  function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'`

Comment: I got that question the first time that I ran the code, but then I deleted the code and started over from scratch. Then at that point, the error didn't occur again, but neither did any other output.

Comment: I also had the same issue, if you do this in R console, it just terminate the session after the first warning. Probably, because the Rcpp required by DescTools is not uptodate

Comment: It is always good to check the behavior in R console because the IDE can mask the behavior and if it is in shiny, it is another layer and we would never know what exactly is going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to get the `Mode`, another option is to create one using `base R` options

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

-testing

```
> Mode(my_data)
[1] 15
```